# Database for iMac App

Tags: mysql, macos, mariadb

I'm considering how to put a software package I built in python into the app store. It uses mariaDB which I installed via brew. The application can reasonably be expected to have 1mm+ rows. Is it possible to bundle a SQL database with a swift/objective C app for imac (and only iMac)?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to bundle a database in your app?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I don't think you can't. I just don't know how. Ive never done it and couldn't find any good information.